# Is there anything else required to make a copy of whole OS boot?

Tags: installation, linux-distributions

I have just installed Lubuntu onto usb(using unetbootin).Now I want to copy all the files on that usb onto a new usb to make it boot Lubuntu too.

Will this work or is there anything else required to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you copy the partitions/mbr/gpt 1:1 there's nothing you'll have to do.

You may as well just copy all files, but you'll have to ensure that the partition is marked as active (and you're using the proper disc format for your BIOS, i.e. MBR vs. GPT).